# Regex validation failed for SEDOL no

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I'M trying to implement the SEDOL (Stock Exchange Daily Official List) validation.
I've try to use the Regex pattern provided over internet.

```
[B-Db-dF-Hf-hJ-Nj-nP-Tp-tV-Xv-xYyZz0-9\d]{6}
```

But, Somehow this regex pattern is not working or it dnt match the validation pattern.

SEDOL NO validation Pattern is show as below:
1234567,9123451,9123_51 invalid
0709954,B0YBKJ7 Valid one

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> ^([A-Z0-9]{6})\d$

Try with this

Comment: should replace this validation?